# Customize Html.ValidationMessageFor doesn't work in client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, client-side-validation

I am working on  mvc3 application, i have created a custom validationMessage to validate a simple field. This custom validationMessage only show an div with title and message instead of  the default span, i have this :

```
@Html.ValidationMessageCustomFor(model => model.FirstName)
```

This is the code to my custom validation:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationCustomFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    string propertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    string name = helper.AttributeEncode(helper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(propertyName));

    if (helper.ViewData.ModelState[name] == null ||
        helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors == null ||
        helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors.Count == 0)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }

    StringBuilder htmlValidation = new StringBuilder();

    htmlValidation.AppendLine("<div>");
    htmlValidation.AppendLine("<table>");
    htmlValidation.AppendLine("<tr>");
    htmlValidation.AppendLine("<td><img src='/Content/Imgages/Error.jpg'></td>");
    htmlValidation.AppendLine("</tr>");
    htmlValidation.AppendLine("<tr>");
    htmlValidation.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", name);
    htmlValidation.AppendLine("</tr>");
    htmlValidation.AppendLine("<tr>");
    htmlValidation.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors[0].ErrorMessage);
    htmlValidation.AppendLine("</tr>");
    htmlValidation.AppendLine("</table>");
    htmlValidation.AppendLine("</div>");

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(htmlValidation.ToString());

}
```

This works fine when I use server side validation, but when I active client side validation it doesn't work.

The default Html.ValidationMessageFor yes works fine with client side validation, but my custom Html.ValidationMessageCustomFor doesn't work.

Could you please help me, any ideas?

---

I modified my custom helper, I added the "data-valmsg-for" atrib for the span, it is the code :

```
 public static MvcHtmlString ValidationCustomFor2<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        string propertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        string name = helper.AttributeEncode(helper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(propertyName));

        if (helper.ViewData.ModelState[name] == null ||
            helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors == null ||
            helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors.Count == 0)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("span");
        tag.Attributes.Add("class", "field-validation-error");
        tag.Attributes.Add("data-valmsg-for", name);
        tag.Attributes.Add("data-valmsg-replace", "true");

        var text = tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag);
        text += "<b>My custom html</b>";
        text += tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag);


        return MvcHtmlString.Create(text);

    }
```

But it doesn't appear, it looks I should do something from the client side, but I don't know WHAT? Any ideas please?

Comment: What is the "ValidationMessageCustomFor" helper method that you're using? There's no such helper method in the MVC3 framework. Is that a helper that you've coded yourself?

Comment: Yes, it is my custom helper, it simply show a div with the validation message, an title and an image, it works fine in server side validation, but when i active the client side it doesn't work, the div with image doesn't appear. Could you please give me some ideas about what is the problem?

Comment: If there's a problem, it should be related to your custom helper method. Could you post code snippets of what it is doing, and how it performs the validation?

Comment: I should also add this, that if your code (in the helper method) is responsible for validation, the MVC framework doesn't automatically take this logic to JavaScript and do the validation in client side. If you need to perform such validations in the client, you should be emitting javascript code snippets to the client to perform the validation before posting the form.

Comment: Hello Iravanchi, it is the code for my custom validation helper:

Comment: Iravanchi, i updated my question with the code for my custom validation helper, could you please give some example about how "emitting javascript code snippets to the client to perform the validation before posting the form" Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please see my edited answer below. When you have unobtrusive client-side validation enabled, you place the validation logic automatically in the page by using the standard helpers to place inputs on the page (like @Html.TextBoxFor, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.NET MVC3 validation works using both server-side and client-side methods.

When you write server-side code to add validation messages to the rendered page (like in your helper method), the code is only invoked when the request is actually sent to the server, while the client-side validation, when enabled, prevents the request from being sent back to the server.

Default implementation of MVC3 client-side validation works using a technique called Unobtrusive JavaScript validation, by adding some `data-` attributes to the page, and then finding and manipulating the marked elements in the JavaScript.

For understanding the Unobtrusive JavaScript validation, try searching for it, there's a ton of resources out there. For example:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CustomClientSideValidatio.aspx

In your case, when you want to specify where to display the validation message, you should mark the HTML element with a `data-valmsg-for` attribute. For example:

```
<SPAN data-valmsg-for="id_of_the_input_to_validate"></span>
```

The validation JavaScript will look for the above attribute and fill the `SPAN` with the validation message in case the input is not valid. Again, this happens before the postback of the form, so your server-side code that shows the validation message is never called, because the validation prevents the form from submitting.

Here's a code snippet from the actual validation message helper included in the MVC3:

```
TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("span"); 
...
if (htmlHelper.ViewContext.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled) {
    builder.MergeAttribute("data-valmsg-for", modelName); 
    builder.MergeAttribute("data-valmsg-replace", replaceValidationMessageContents.ToString().ToLowerInvariant());
}
```

---

Edit: Reply to your edited question:

The first time the page is rendered, your first `if` is `true` (there is no validation error messages to render), thus you return an empty string. Your page will not have any of the `data-` attributes in it.

You should render the `<span data-valmsg-for="..."></span>` all the time, even when you don't have any error messages, so that the JavaScript library knows where to put the error in case it happens on the client side.