# Render HTML tags inside of HTML.ValidationMessageFor in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to show a link as part of the validation message for a field.
I'm using data attributes with custom error messages to set it:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Message <a href='#'>link</a>")]
public string Field{ get; set; }
```

But when it renders the tags are escaped and literally prints:

```
Message <a href='#'>link</a>
```

Is it possible to have the link as part of the validation message but render correctly?

**In case anyone's interested, here's how I accomplished it**

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationHTMLMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    return ValidationHTMLMessageFor(helper, expression, (object)null);
}
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationHTMLMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
    return ValidationHTMLMessageFor(helper, expression, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
}
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationHTMLMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    string propertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    string name = helper.AttributeEncode(helper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(propertyName));

    if (helper.ViewData.ModelState[name] == null ||
        helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors == null ||
        helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors.Count == 0)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }

    string errors = "";
    foreach (ModelError error in helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors)
    {
        TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("span");
        tag.Attributes.Add("class", HtmlHelper.ValidationMessageCssClassName);
        tag.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        tag.Attributes.Add("data-valmsg-for", name);
        tag.Attributes.Add("data-valmsg-replace", "true");

        var text = tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag);
        text += error.ErrorMessage;
        text += tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag);
        errors += text;
    }

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(errors);

}
```

Thanks Darin for pointing me in the right direction. I also found this that I used as a template [Customize Html.ValidationMessageFor doesn't work in client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004105/customize-html-validationmessagefor-doesnt-work-in-client-side).

I'm new to this, so if anyone has any suggestions, please post.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The code above doesn't work with client-side validation since it doesn't produce the tags required for client-side validation.

Here's an improvement on it that does that:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationHTMLMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
  string propertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
  string name = helper.AttributeEncode(helper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(propertyName));

  TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("span");
  tag.Attributes.Add("class", HtmlHelper.ValidationMessageCssClassName);
  tag.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
  tag.Attributes.Add("data-valmsg-for", name);
  tag.Attributes.Add("data-valmsg-replace", "true");
  var returnTag = new StringBuilder(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));

  if (helper.ViewData.ModelState[name] != null &&
      helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors != null &&
      helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors.Count > 0)
  {
    foreach (ModelError error in helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors)
    {
      returnTag.Append(error.ErrorMessage);
    }
  }
  returnTag.Append(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));
  return MvcHtmlString.Create(returnTag.ToString());
}
```

Thanks for the original post - it was very helpful!

Comment: Just posted an answer based on your's

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible but not with the standard helpers (`ValidationSummary` and `ValidationMessageFor`). You will have to write a custom helper to render those messages if you want to achieve that. You may take a look at the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8158918/29407) for an example of how to write a custom `ValidationSummary` helper that doesn't HTML encode the error messages as the standard one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using MVC4 so I can't say for sure about MVC3.

The only way I was able to insert a `<br>` tag (in my case), was to start with Jerode's method, but I also had to put a marker in the message string and replace it in the razor.  So the sent message was `"Line 1[BR]Line2"`.  The razor was `@Html.Raw(Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.MyProperty).ToString().Replace("[BR]", "&lt;br&gt;"))`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to just put the validation item inside of the Html.Raw.

```
@Html.Raw(Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.MyProperty))
```

This is not as nice as the approach as the suggestions but should accomplish what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from @shycohen:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString HtmlValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        string propertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        string name = helper.AttributeEncode(helper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(propertyName));

        TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("span");

        tag.Attributes.Add("data-valmsg-for", name);
        tag.Attributes.Add("data-valmsg-replace", "true");

        if (htmlAttributes != null)
        {
            tag.MergeAttributes((IDictionary<string, object>)HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
        }

        tag.AddCssClass(HtmlHelper.ValidationMessageCssClassName);

        var returnTag = new StringBuilder(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));

        if (helper.ViewData.ModelState[name] != null &&
            helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors != null &&
            helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (ModelError error in helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors)
            {
                returnTag.Append(error.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }

        returnTag.Append(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(returnTag.ToString());
    }
```

The `htmlAttributes` parameter is now optional and passed as an anonymous object to closer match `ValidationMessageFor`.

The other issue was not being able to add extra classes via `htmlAttributes`, as `TagBuilder.MergeAttributes` doesn't merge attribute values. This is solved by using `TagBuilder.AddCssClass` *after* merging the attributes to set the validation class.