# New Line Character in mvc3 model In errormesaage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I'm using MVC 3 web application and i have give error message with 
 tag but br tag not working in mvc 3 if i used mvc4 then its working fine
below are the code whioch i used.

MODEL :

```
 [Required]
 [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be <br/> at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
 [DataType(DataType.Password)]
 [Display(Name = "Password")]
 public string Password { get; set; }
```

CSHTML :

```
 <div class="editor-field">
  @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
 </div>
```

Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using html in ErrorMessage property of data annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871495/using-html-in-errormessage-property-of-data-annotations)

Comment: Dear, i have do that only c# without  jquery

Comment: Try this `@Html.Raw(Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password).ToString())`